# How to create JSON Codable using Swift

Tags: ios, swift

In my case, I am trying to get data from my JSON. I found codable one of the easiest way to get and maintain data from `JSON` in `iOS`. I would like to know how to convert below my JSON to `Codable`.

My JSON Below

```
{  
   "status": true,
   "data" : {  
      "school":[  
          {  
            "id":"01",
            "name":"Avision",
            "date":"12 - 01 - 2018",
            "group":["A","B","C"]
         },
         {  
            "id":"01",
            "name":"Bvision",
            "date":"12 - 01 - 2018",
            "group":["A","B","C"]
         }

      ],
      "college":[ 
          {  
            "id":"01",
            "name":"Avision",
            "date":"12 - 01 - 2018",
            "group":["A","B","C"]
         },
         {  
            "id":"01",
            "name":"Bvision",
            "date":"12 - 01 - 2018",
            "group":["A","B","C"]
         }

      ],
      "office":[  
          {  
            "id":"01",
            "name":"Avision",
            "date":"12 - 01 - 2018",
            "group":["A","B","C"]
         },
         {  
            "id":"01",
            "name":"Bvision",
            "date":"12 - 01 - 2018",
            "group":["A","B","C"]
         }

      ],
      "organisation":[  
          {  
            "id":"01",
            "name":"Avision",
            "date":"12 - 01 - 2018",
            "group":["A","B","C"]
         },
         {  
            "id":"01",
            "name":"Bvision",
            "date":"12 - 01 - 2018",
            "group":["A","B","C"]
         }

      ],
      "central":[  
         {  
            "id":"01",
            "name":"Avision",
            "date":"12 - 01 - 2018",
            "group":["A","B","C"]
         },
         {  
            "id":"01",
            "name":"Bvision",
            "date":"12 - 01 - 2018",
            "group":["A","B","C"]
         }
      ]
   }
}
```

Here, Multiple array of multiple values available, It will increase and sometime may have a chance to show empty array based on server data. How to create `codable`.

Comment: Don't repost questions. You have asked a lot of similar questions in the past days. Rather than reposting the question improve your existing question(s) by editing and adding more information partially requested in the comments.

Comment: @vadian Thank you so much. btw I didn't repost its my new doubt but it may looks same. I would like to learn here, Please provide me some solution.

Comment: You got the advice to use https://quicktype.io in one of your previous questions, have you tried it and have you done any research into using `Codable`? And your question is to broad, requesting to much at the same time. Try to research and ask about one subject at a time.

Comment: @Joakim Danielson I am asking only one question how to change above JSON to Codable. I used **quick type.io** but its not generated correct one.

Comment: Yes now you are, good. If you think QuickType didn't generate the correct structure then you must have some code and an idea what is wrong with it and what you would want it to do.

Comment: @ Joakim Danielson If you don't mind can you please check it quick type.io for above my JSON. This             "group":["A","B","C"] key and its array values generating wrong format.

Comment: I think it creates those enum types because your json has the same data in all `date` and `group` fields so it gets fooled by that. See the answer by @vadian below for a correct implementation

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/197968/discussion-between-ios-dev-and-joakim-danielson).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a starting point. The structs are pretty straightforward. If one of the `Division` arrays is empty – asked in one of your previous questions – the corresponding array is empty, too.

```
struct Root : Decodable {
    let status : Bool
    let data: DivisionData
}

struct DivisionData : Decodable {
    let school, college, office, organisation, central : [Division]
}

struct Division : Decodable {
    let id, name, date : String
    let group : [String]
}
```

Comment: but I am getting error while trying to get Root Value

Comment: **What** error? The structs definitely **do** decode the JSON in the question if you write `JSONDecoder().decode(Root.self, from:...`. However if this is pseudo-JSON I can't help you.

Comment: Getting Error: libMobileGestalt MobileGestalt.c:890: MGIsDeviceOneOfType is not supported on this platform.
keyNotFound(CodingKeys(stringValue: "group", intValue: nil), Swift.DecodingError.Context(codingPath: [CodingKeys(stringValue: "data", intValue: nil), CodingKeys(stringValue: "central", intValue: nil), _JSONKey(stringValue: "Index 0", intValue: 0)], debugDescription: "No value associated with key CodingKeys(stringValue: \"group\", intValue: nil) (\"group\").", underlyingError: nil))

Comment: If a division doesn't have a group make it optional `let group : [String]?` Why don't you provide real data?

Comment: fantastic solution. Its working Thanks Master :)

Comment: May i know why I am getting **CodableJSON.Division**  in my response? [CodableJSON.Division(id: "01", name: "Avision", date: "12 - 01 - 2018", group: ["A", "B", "C"]), CodableJSON.Division(id: "01", name: "Bvision", date: "12 - 01 - 2018", group: ["A", "B", "C"])] @vadian

Comment: This is the Swift namespace convention. If the enclosing class/struct of `Division` is `CodableJSON` the identifier is `CodableJSON.Division`

Comment: I have one more doubt If suppose anything array empty from above four arrays, i am getting all response just [ ]. Can you please tell me why its happening?

Comment: `[]` represents an empty array. Prove it by printing for example `.data.central.count`. You'll get 0 if the array is empty

Comment: Great. Thanks a lot. I learned manythings from you. @vadian